# Javafx Virtual Desktop Windows10/OSX

Tags: macos, javafx, windows-10, javafx-8, virtual-desktop

I have a Javafx desktop application with multiple stages and i want to move each window in particular positions. I also have to manage multiple virtual desktops available in Windows10 and OSX.
How can I put a stage in a particular virtual desktop in Win10 or OSX (and create a new one if it doesn't exist)?